# c++ navigate through array by moving pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In the following I expected 13 to be printed. 
I wanted to move arr (which is a pointer to the memory, where int values from array are stored, if i understand everything right) by the size of one array member, which is int.

Instead 45 is printed. So instead making one array-member-wide jump the 5th Array member is retrieved. Why?

```
int arr[] = {1,13,25,37,45,56};
int val = *( arr + 4 );         //moving the pointer by the sizeof(int)=4
std::cout << "Array Val: " << val << std::endl;
```

Comment: This pertains to behavior of standard pointer arithmetic for arrays.  More can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. It moves the pointer 4 elements ahead, not 4 bytes ahead.

`*(arr + 4)` is like saying in that logic `*(arr + 4 * sizeof (arr [0]))`.

The statement `*(arr + 4)` is equivalent to `arr [4]`. It does make for some neat syntax, though, as `*(4 + arr)` is equally valid, meaning so is `4 [arr]`.

Your behaviour could be achieved through the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {65,66,67};
    char *b = reinterpret_cast<char *>(a);
    std::cout << *(b + sizeof (int)); //prints 'B'
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using `reinterpret_cast` for this purpose though.

Comment: so this is a syntax thing? `(arr+x)` accesses the array? How can I change the memory address then?

Comment: The `arr + x` part is part of pointer arithmetic rules. `arr + 1` advances to the next element of the type that `arr` points to.

Comment: aha - this I wanted to understand. And what happens, if the type of the pointer is `void*` ?

Comment: @Skip, the `-pedantic` flag should stop you if you try to use `void *` in pointer arithmetic. I've updated my answer to replicate your assumed behaviour.

Comment: Why should that print `B`? There's no justification for it, and, on a big endian machine, it won't.

Comment: @jpalecek, that precise example prints `B` for me and doesn't give any warnings, but you're correct in saying that. I did recommend not to do it.

Comment: @chris, thnx - I understand, that the reinterpret_cast example is for academical purpose only. Now I understand the whole pointer thing much better.

Comment: `arr [4]` is certainly the neater syntax but I wonder why Dennis Ritchie didn't prohibit the syntax `4[arr]` from being valid in the language. It is not neat and affects readability very badly. Ultimately I have to read the expression `4[arr]` from right to left to make a sense out of it.

Comment: @RBT, Making special cases that don't really buy you anything fills up the standard with pointless text. That's one reason to consider making the rules more general and accepting any consequences. I suppose it's also possible he didn't realize that `4[arr]` was a consequence in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

`arr + 4` will give you 4 items on from the start address of the array, not 4 bytes. That's why you get 45 which is the zeroth item plus 4.

Answer (score 0):

It is performing pointer arithmetic. See this: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html

`arr` is your array and this decomposes to the first element `arr[0]` which will be `1`, then you `+ 4` to it which moves the pointer by 4 elements `arr[4]` so it is now pointing to `45`.

Comment: So then it should be 5? Because 4 plus the first_array_element(which is 1) should be 5?

Comment: @Skip No, your array is composed of ints, when you increment the pointer you are moving the pointer to the next element you are not adding 4 to the value of the first element `int val = (*arr) + 4 ;` this would produce 5 as you dereference the first element which is 1 and then add 4 what you are doing is incrementing the pointer by 4 positions